# What changes would the City Domain (UA) need to work in Waterdeep?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-settings, unearthed-arcana, domains, waterdeep-dragon-heist

I am hoping to start running Dragon Heist in the near future (leading in to Dungeon of the Mad Mage) and would like to make the [Unearthed Arcana City Domain](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_ModernMagic.pdf) available to users. While it introduces limited firearms, I think some changes will be necessary to make it fit the setting - I think it's just the features below (though I am happy to be persuaded otherwise). What would a fair replacement be?

**What probably needs to go?**

- The sidearm proficiency
- Spells: On/Off, Remote Access, Protection from Ballistics, Shutdown

Comment: Have you read the dragon heist adventure through yet?  I am not sure that side arm proficiency is a problem.  Suggest taking a more detailed look and revising the question.

Comment: As phrased, this seems to be an attempt to brainstorm ideas for your homebrew, which isn't what SE is suited for.

Comment: Apologies, you're quite right, in retrospect there is no right answer for this, so I should have asked elsewhere. If you can think of a way to reframe the question in a useful way, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The *City Domain* is aimed at clerics in modern cities, so it's hardly suitable for Dragon Heist.

Regardless of which features remain, most of them will be near-useless in a classic setting such as the one from Dragon Heist. If you want a "middle-age-fantasy city domain", you'll mostly have to homebrew (although you can certainly take inspiration from the UA domain).

Either way, let's take a look at the features gained by the domain:

- Domain spells: >50% of the spells refer to modern technologies, like computers or firearms, and are therefore unsuited for a classic fantasy setting.
- Bonus cantrip: same thing.
- Bonus proficiencies: same thing, although "land vehicle proficiency" is also a thing in classic settings. But for real, how often do you use vehicles in your campaign? Mostly to travel between towns, in which case you can hire a guy. Unlike in modern times, you don't chase bad guys with your vehicle, since horses without a vehicle attached are simply a lot faster.
- Heart of the City: works fine.
- CD: Spirits of the City: not entirely useless, but flavorwise not particularly well-suited and not as effective as it would be in a modern city.
- Block Watch: works fine.
- Divine Strike: works fine.
- Express Transit: depends on if you have bus stops in Waterdeep (just kidding, it's useless)

As you can see, most features are useless in a classic fantasy setting like Waterdeep. Sure, some are valid, but I highly doubt that any of your players will want to use a domain that's unuseable 60% of the time.

If you *do* want to provide a "city domain" option for your players, I suggest you make a homebrew subclass. That goes along the lines of what you're already asking, but RPG SE doesn't design homebrew starting from zero. Once you've got a first draft, you can ask for help on improving it.

Comment: NB that though they’re rare, there are firearms in the Forgotten Realms, especially along the Sword Coast. Gond’s priests make them.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie *especially* in the AP in question, where they're kind of a big deal. (At least they were pretty impactful when I ran it.)

Comment: Many thanks for the response and comments. I will have a look through the adventure for sidearms - I had seen that the adventure featured gunslingers.